# Exclude files when using "Find Usages" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In Java source files, when I select a class or a method, then click the right button of mouse, in the pop up context menu, and run `Find Usages`, the files that use the class or methods are searched out.

But I would like to *exclude* certain files (e.g. JUnit test files) from the search results.

Where could I configure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea//2017.1/find-usages.html); you can confgure the `Find Usages` scope by clicking on the tools icon in the top left hand corner of the `Find Usages` results.

Here are some screenshots:

- Click on the tools icon here:

[image]

- Click on the build button (`...` next to the `Scope` field) to create a `Scope` and define it like so (in this examples I have included production classes and excluded test classes):

[image]

- Choose that scope in the `Find Usages` dialog:

[image]

Notes:

1. You can also chose the precanned scope named `Project Production Files` from the `Scope` dropdown
2. All subsequent searches will use this scope **by default** until you choose a different scope.